# HTML special code to ASCII

Tags: php, html, replace, special-characters

Hey, is there any built in functions or something like that in php that will allow me to turn HTML special code like: <(;), >(;), Á(;) and ©(;) etc... into <, >, Á and ©

Lets say I have the value:

```
$fileName = "Gibt es eine schö(;)ne Offroadstrecke? (;)";
```

And I want this:

```
$fileName = "Gibt es eine schöne Offroadstrecke? ";
```

Any easy way to do this with php? The first I though of was to make a function that hard codes replaceing all of the HTML, search each string for the codes and replace but that is a whole lot of code in the end. :)

Comment: I have a feeling your formatting has been messed up by StackOverflow -- is that right? Or did you really intend (;)? I'm assuming you're really meaning that the filename has an HTML entity in it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want [html_entity_decode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php)

Comment: You can use '\' to escape underscores, e.g. html\_entity\_decode

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason you can't simply do a RegEx (or some other tool) to search and replace for "(;)" ?